# How to access 2nd key of a multidimensional Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have the following dictionary. I want to extract 2nd key of certain index. e.g.
I tried **list(results.keys())[2]** which gives me entire row of that index
***'DV[May2021,Journey3]'***. But, I want only the 2nd key: "**Journey3**".

```
 DV[May2021, Journey1]: 0,
 DV[May2021, Journey2]:1,
 DV[May2021, Journey3]:1,
 DV[june2021, Journey1]:0,
 DV[june2021, Journey2]:2,
 DV[june2021, Journey3]:0,
 DV[july2021, Journey1]:3,
 DV[july2021, Journey2]:2,
 DV[july2021, journey3]:2,
 DV[aug2021, Journey1]:2
```

Comment: All key is in same formate?

Comment: yes they are...

Comment: Can you give us the structure of DV  object?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
test_dict = {
 "DV[May2021, Journey1]":0,
 "DV[May2021, Journey2]":1,
 "DV[May2021, Journey3]":1,
 "DV[june2021, Journey1]":0,
 "DV[june2021, Journey2]":2,
 "DV[june2021, Journey3]":0,
 "DV[july2021, Journey1]":3,
 "DV[july2021, Journey2]":2,
 "DV[july2021, journey3]":2,
 "DV[aug2021, Journey1]":2
}
keys = list(test_dict)[2]
print(keys[keys.index("["):keys.index("]")].split()[1])
```

Output:

```
Journey3
```

Comment: Thanks Hiral. Your code worked great for me with minor edit.